# PHP not echoing variables when print_r does

Tags: php

I'm not sure exactly what is going on but when a user clicks a submit button on an html page and the php script runs I get the print out from the print_r statement, but if I print a variable out with the echo statement, the value isn't returned.  I've just ported the webpage and code over to a new computer, would that have something to do with it?  Here is my sample php code:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);

$x = $_POST[minAcres];
echo $x;

?>
```

Everything was working fine until I moved the code.  Any thoughts why this would be happening? Here is a screenshot of the output from the print_r command.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `minAcres` is the name of the key?

Comment: BTW, you should quote `minAcres`, although PHP will automatically quote it and issue a warning about it.

Comment: Your php is wrong, it should  be `$_POST["minAcres"];`

Comment: @Lk77 PHP will automatically convert it to a string literal unless there's a constant named `minAcres`.

Comment: it's not a good idea to not correct that mistake, because it will not always work, in a class it can cause a `Error : Undefined constant`

Comment: I'm positive the name of one of the keys is minAcres.  I also updated the post to show a screenshot of the print_r command.

Comment: @Lk77 Of course it's a good idea to correct the mistake, that's why I wrote my second comment.

Comment: I tried it and in apache i got a `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "minAcres" `, there is perhaps setups where it will be converted to a string automagically but don't count on it and wrap in `"`, i guess it depends on the php.ini file

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($x);` to see what that prints out?

Comment: var_dump($x) didn't provide anything different unfortunately.

Comment: Is that code copied/pasted from your file or did you type it here? (Make sure you don't have a any typos/whitespace in it). Is that all the code from the file? Does echo $_POST["maxAcres"]; work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example I regress back to the original answer of needing just quotes around minAcres. As a proof of concept i filled in post array with the beginning few values from your screen shot. minAcres = 0. Output = '0'. Maybe your output has been formatted to not show the 0 but show blank/empty

```
<?php

$_POST = array(
'selectCountries' => array('Columbia'),
'startDate' => '2001-01-01',
'minAcres' => 0
);
print_r($_POST);

$x = $_POST['minAcres'];
echo $x;

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[selectCountries] => Array
    (
        [0] => Columbia
    )

[startDate] => 2001-01-01
[minAcres] => 0
)
0
```

Simple syntax error

```
$x = $_POST['minAcres'];
```

quotes needed around array's key.

Comment: Adding single quotes around the key still doesn't echo out the variable value.

Comment: You may want to look further up stream on your code. Check your html has a <form> tag or $_POST will not populate. Also confirm your addressing the right key. If you show the output of your results from 'print_r' would be more helpful in a diagnosis too.

Comment: The html does indeed have a <for> tag.  The output from the 'print_r' is located in the screenshot above.

Comment: Does 'selectCountries' have to be an array? You are creating a 2D array with your first value but inside the second array is only 1 value. The one value array should be stripped down to stop having a 2D array. If you keep the array then your echo would need to be $_POST[1]['minAcres']

Comment: It does have to be an array because the user is able to select up to 72 different counties in order to query the database.

Comment: if you are on a new computer/server verify with phpinfo() you have extensions like 'mbstring' and 'intl' installed. you maye have been missing something during turnover. these extensions are needed to display some types of output

Comment: both computers have 'mbstring' but not 'intl'.  The only thing that is slightly different is that the new computer uses Vicusal C++2019 as the Compiler and the other one uses 2017.

Comment: The use of a single quote is now working.  I have no idea what is going on with it.  I tried single and double quotes before, then restarted the computer and tried single and double quotes again and it still didn't give me anything.  Went back to single quotes and now it's working.  Glitch in the software maybe?  It's also weird that on my old computer it didn't need the single quotes at all.